# How do I declare IPrincipal variables in Layout page in Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I declare `IPrincipal` variables in layout page in Mvc 5.

i.e. when login I store all the value in `IPrincipal` class here:

```
 CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

 CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
 newUser.UserID = serializeModel.UserID;
 newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;

 newUser.UserType = serializeModel.UserType;
 newUser.Fk_Parent = serializeModel.Fk_Parent;
 newUser.CompanyID = serializeModel.CompanyID;
 newUser.Address = serializeModel.Address;
 newUser.Profile = serializeModel.Profile;
 newUser.Company = serializeModel.Company;
 HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
```

So how can I access the value of `UserType` in layout page?

I cannot access like `@User.UserType` in layout page.

Answer (score 0):

The User property of the layout is of type IPrincipal which does not decalre the property you are trying to access.

Trying doing this

```
var userType = ((CustomPrincipal)User).UserType
```

or this

```
var user = User as CustomPrincipal;
var userType = user.UserType;
```

Comment: i want to use it on layout page

Comment: In Layout page how can i use it??I am using a partial view name LeftMenu and in that partial view i need the value of @user.UserType but i cannot solve

Comment: @mmm I guess you could do this: `<span>@(((CustomPrincipal)User).UserType)</span>`

Comment: THE TYPE OF THE NAMESPACE CustomPrincipal COULD NOT BE FOUND

Comment: Is there any other way to call??'

Comment: is there any one can tell me what should i do??

Comment: @mmm `<span>@(((<YOURNAMESPACE>.CustomPrincipal)User).UserType)</span>` should work. Or better yet, add `@using <YOURNAMESPACE>` to the top of your layout and `<span>@(((CustomPrincipal)User).UserType)</span>` should start working as well.